# PHP parsing XML data and draw HTML Table

Tags: php, html-table, xml-parsing

I have a case where i need to parse a "Products specifications" XML style document (data) that looks like this:

```xml
    <Message>
    <EntityType>Document</EntityType>
    <ProductSETS>
      <Entity>
       <id>1</id>
       <Specification1>Human readable title 1</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Human readable title 2</Specification2>
       <Price>Product Price</Price>
       [...more elements of same row amount...]
      </Entity>
    
      <Entity>
       <id>100</id>
       <Specification1>Red</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Square</Specification2>
       <Price>8888</Price>
       [...more elements of same row amount...]
      </Entity>
    
      <Entity>
       <id>101</id>
       <Specification1>Blue</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Round</Specification2>
       <Price>9999</Price>
       [...more elements of same row amount...]
      </Entity>
    
    </ProductSETS>
    </Message>
```

And in short i need, with the help of trustworthy PHP, to print a table that contains the XML data like:

```
_____________________________________________________________________
| ProductSET for ID 100                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Human readable title 1                 |  Red                     |
| Human readable title 2                 |  Square                  |
| Product Price                          |  8888                    |
| Next element in human readable form    |  ID. 100 ELEMENT [...]   |
[   .... and loop until end of <Entity> <id>100</id>  ............. |
_____________________________________________________________________
| ProductSET for ID 101                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Human readable title 1                 |  Blue                    |
| Human readable title 2                 |  Round                   |
| Product Price                          |  9999                    |
| Next element in human readable form    |  ID. 101 ELEMENT [...]   |
[   .... and loop until end of <Entity> <id>101</id>  ............. |
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Notice that the xml always has the first entity as a "header"-like entry where 1 is used to map the "Human readable" value of the products specifications titles
and after the "header" entity the actual product specifications value are present (Color, Size, Price etc.)

The catch is that i need two ways to display a table in HTML with values from XML data:

Listing all  (without entity with 1, but still use values from it on all the rest)

```
foreach ($feed->ProductSETS->Entity) :
if(ProductSETS->Entity->id != "1"){
  <tr><th><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[1]->Specification1 ?>:</th>
<td><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[100]->Title->Value ?> (Red)</td> </tr>
  <tr><th><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[1]->Specification2 ?>:</th>
<td><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[100]->Title->Value ?> (Square)</td> </tr>

  <tr><th><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[1]->Specification1 ?>:</th>
<td><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[101]->Title->Value ?> (Blue)</td>
</tr>
  <tr><th><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[1]->Specification2 ?>:</th>
<td><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[101]->Title->Value ?> (Round)</td> </tr>
}
endforeach;
```

Selective listing table where if a $filter = "101" draw table only for product ID 101 but still use data from id. 1 to show human readable product specifications for single ID 101 product:

```
foreach ($feed->ProductSETS->Entity) :
  if(ProductSETS->Entity->id == "101"){
  <tr><th><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[1]->Specification1 ?>:</th>
<td><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[101]->Title->Value ?> (Blue)</td> </tr>
  <tr><th><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[1]->Specification2 ?>:</th>
<td><? echo ProductSETS->Entity->[101]->Title->Value ?> (Round)</td> </tr>
  }else{ echo "No matching product search criteria"; }
endforeach;
```

I think i got the best out of my "explanations techniques", sorry for the "story" length, and hope someone out there can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found. Code is writen by [Barand](https://forums.phpfreaks.com/profile/3105-barand/) and the script does this:

- Parses a XML data with multiple Entity entries
- Uses 1st Entry as "title" column (Entry ID 1)
- Outputs each other Entry in columns in a "comparable-style" horizontal html table
- Has a "filter" mode where certain Entries can be "compared"
- Modifies values of 1st Entry only (to remove default "1" values)

The script does not reorganize Entries (rows) in the HTML table (they are in the same order as XML data).

```
<?php
// Code writen by Barand - https://forums.phpfreaks.com/profile/3105-barand/
// Donate to Barand - https://www.paypal.me/baandrew - if you found this script usefull !
$xml = "
<Message>
    <EntityType>Document</EntityType>
    <ProductSETS>
      <Entity>
       <id>1</id>
       <sku>1</sku>
       <ean>1</ean>
       <Specification1>Name</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Color</Specification2>
       <Specification3>Type</Specification3>
       <Specification4>Manufacturer</Specification4>
       <Price>Product Price</Price>
      </Entity>
    
      <Entity>
       <id>100</id>
       <sku>prod-0001</sku>
       <ean>5901234123456</ean>
       <Specification1>Lorem ipsum</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Red</Specification2>
       <Specification3>Hybrid car</Specification3>
       <Specification4>Tesla</Specification4>
       <Price>10000</Price>
       </Entity>
    
      <Entity>
       <id>101</id>
       <sku>prod-0002</sku>
       <ean>5907171819916</ean>
       <Specification1>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Blue</Specification2>
       <Specification3>Diesel car</Specification3>
       <Specification4>Trabant</Specification4>
       <Price>5000</Price>
       </Entity>

      <Entity>
       <id>102</id>
       <sku>prod-0003</sku>
       <ean>6189192737718</ean>
       <Specification1>Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation</Specification1>
       <Specification2>Black</Specification2>
       <Specification3>SUV</Specification3>
       <Specification4>Hummer</Specification4>
       <Price>1</Price>
       </Entity>
       
       
    </ProductSETS>
</Message>
";
$chosen = $_GET['choice'] ?? [];

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$heads = $prods = [];
$tdata = '';

if ($chosen) {
    $h = $feed->xpath('//Entity[id = 1]')[0];         // headings from entity #1
    $p = $feed->xpath('//Entity[id > 1]');            // products from rest of entities
    foreach ($h as $k=>$v) {
        $heads[$k] = (in_array($k, ['id','sku','ean'])) ? '' : (string)$h->$k;
        if (!isset($prods[$k])) {
            $prods[$k] = [ 'heading' => $heads[$k],
                           'specs'   => []
                         ];
        }
    }
    foreach ($p as $spec) {
        if (!in_array((string)$spec->id, $chosen)) continue;
        foreach ($spec as $k=>$s) {
            $prods[$k]['specs'][] = trim((string)$s);
        }
    }

    foreach ($prods as $k => $row) {
        if ($k=='id') continue;
        $tdata .= "<tr><th>{$row['heading']}</th>";
        $tdata .= '<td>' . join('</td><td>', $row['specs']) . "</td></tr>\n";
    }
}
/**
* build list of checkbox options for product selection
* 
* @param simplexmlobj $feed
*/
function productOptions($feed) 
{
    $prods = $feed->xpath('//Entity[id > 1]');
    $opts = '';
    foreach ($prods as $p) {
        $opts .= "&emsp;<label><input type='checkbox' name='choice[]' value='{$p->id}'> {$p->sku}</label>\n";
    }
    return $opts;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style type='text/css'>
    td {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    th {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-container w3-blue-gray w3=padding">
    <h1>Product Comparison</h1>
</div>
<form class="w3-container w3-light-gray w3-padding-24">
    Select products to compare &emsp; <?=productOptions($feed)?>
    &emsp;
    <button class='w3-button w3-blue w3-round'>Compare</button>
</form>   
<div class="w3-continer w3-responsive w3-padding w3-margin-top">
    <table class="w3-table-all">
        <?= $tdata ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

result is:
[image: Barand coded script]